# SMS Broadcast Receiver works in debug only with emulator

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I have an app that tries to catch SMS messsages from a specific sender and then starts a new activity. When running in Eclipse using Debug As and using emulator my BroadcastReceiver it works great, it hits the breakpoints as expected. When I use Run As in Eclipse to launch in the emulator the SMS messages never get caught. It appears the BroadcastReceiver is never called based on the lack of Log outputs. The SMSes also do not get caught when running on my phone. Any ideas why it works one way but not another?

I have very few apps on my phone and the only one I know of that catches text messages is the built-in messenger one.

```xml
<receiver android:name=".sms.ConfirmationResponder">
  <intent-filter android:priority="100">
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>

...

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

The receiver:

```java
public class ConfirmationResponder extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.i("SMS", "############################ Confirmation being read");
        // More stuff after this but I don't even get the log message
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you build in release and debug mode?

Comment: I'm just using the Run command in Eclipse to both the emulator and my phone.

Comment: Thus, debug mode you mean in a emulator and release mode in a real phone? Maybe, on a real phone you have ordered intent for SMS receive and standard receiver has higher priority. Try to increase priority (set it to 999). Maybe this helps.

Comment: I meant running both debug and run in Eclipse. When I do a Debug As... it calls the receiver. When I do Run As... it does not. Will clarify my post. Tried increasing priority to no avail. Does the built in messenger app stop broadcasting after it handles an SMS?

Comment: To my experience - no. But I thought that maybe you run your app on a real device and there can be some peculiarities.

Comment: For release mode try to set the flag android:debuggable to false in the manifest file.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my program:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;

public class SMSBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
        private static final String TAG = "SMSBroadcastReceiver";

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             Log.i(TAG, "Intent recieved: " + intent.getAction());

                if (intent.getAction() == SMS_RECEIVED) {
                    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                    if (bundle != null) {
                        Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
                        final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                        for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                            messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                        }
                        if (messages.length > -1) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Message recieved: " + messages[0].getMessageBody());
                        }
                    }
                }
           }
    }
```

And the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="Technicaljar.SMSBroadcastReceiver"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true" >
        <receiver android:name=".SMSBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Hope it Helps

Answer (score 0):

I think it works but eclipse is not attached to device when "Run as" mode and do not show logcat info.